# SQL Statement With Variable From Within Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'd have a sql query where the goal is to find employees with a particular name who have surpassed their sales goal. It looks something like...

```
select *
          from employees
         where name = find_name
            or (sales > projected_sales + bonus_sales)
         order by case when name = find_name and (sales > projected_sales + bonus_sales) then 1
                       when name = find_name then 2
                       else 3
                  end)
```

The problem is that I repeat the condition (sales > projected_sales + bonus_sales), really I'd like to say something along the lines of

```
select *
          from employees
         where name = find_name
            or (sales > projected_sales + bonus_sales) as sales_condition
         order by case when name = find_name and sales_condition then 1
                       when name = find_name then 2
                       else 3
                  end)
```

Where I'm essentially storing the condition after evaluating it once, then reusing it.

Any good solutions to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I see is using a derived query like below.

```
select *
          from ( select *, projected_sales + bonus_sales as total_sales from employees) xx
         where name = find_name
            or (sales > total_sales)
         order by case when name = find_name and (sales > total_sales) then 1
                       when name = find_name then 2
                       else 3
                  end);
```